# Selenium Java Code need to start from begin when changes made to the code

Tags: selenium, execution

I am Using Eclipse, Selenium Web Driver and Java to automate our Web Application.
As part of execution in debug mode, i have made a change in the code and saved.
But the code changes are not reflecting in the current execution, need to restart the execution from the begin.
Please suggest, do we have any solution to continue the execution with the changes made.

Comment: Change code during debug will not reflect until restart debug.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*In this Case,My code is like below

```
public static void Test() throws Exception{

//Lines of Code

Line 1

Line 2

Line 3

Line 4

}
```

I have made changes to the code at Line2 and then Saved the changes
Now the debug execution focus will move to Line 1, now we can continue our execution again in debug mode with out restarting.Like this we can continue our execution with the updated changes.*